# Insert unique values into same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want to insert old values with new date but only the unique ones .

```
t1

ID      |    Block     |    Flats  |
1       |      1       |      GF-1 |
2       |      1       |      GF-2 |
3       |      2       |      GF-1 |
4       |      2       |      GF-2 |
5       |      2       |      GF-2 |
```

this is part of my table with some sample data I want it to become after copy

```
ID      |    Block     |    Flats  |
1       |      1       |      GF-1 |
2       |      1       |      GF-2 |
3       |      2       |      GF-1 |
4       |      2       |      GF-2 |
5       |      2       |      GF-2 |
6       |      1       |      GF-1 |
7       |      1       |      GF-2 |
8       |      2       |      GF-1 |
9       |      2       |      GF-2 |
```

As after copy it only copied the distinct values and GF-2 came only once.
But when I tried

```
insert into t1 (ID,Block,Flats) select distinct Block,Flats from t1
```

It copies that GF-2 twice in block 2.

Note: ID column is incremented by 1 automatically.

Comment: are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in block or flats column?

Comment: @vkp no there are none. and when I just run  select distinct  Block,Flats from t1 it gives exactly the same output I desire with no duplicates

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Comment: @HLGEM No there are no triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all the rows using `cross join`, then weed out the ones that already exist:

```
insert into t1(block, flats)
    select b.block, f.flats
    from (select distinct block from t1) b cross join
         (select distinct flats from t1) f left join
         t1
         on t1.block = b.block and t1.flats = f.flats
    where t1.block is null;
```

Note:  This assumes that `id` is an `identity` column (which is I see you have described as being the case).

Comment: sorry for being a newbie. This was sample. 2 more columns are being entered in actual scenario. What will happen to them in this query case? as I can't seem to figure out from which select will they get their output.